# Cannot access a variable due to the access level protection

Tags: c#

I have following classes:

```
class Department
{
 private string departmentId;
 private string departmentName;
 private Hashtable doctors = new Hashtable();//Store doctors for 
                                                //each department
public Hashtable Doctor
{
 get { return doctors; }
}
}
```

I have an array list that holds department objects:

```
private static ArrayList deptList = new ArrayList();
public ArrayList Dept
{
 get { return deptList; }
}
```

I am trying to get all the doctors(the Hashtable in department class) from each department:

```
foreach (Department department in deptList) 
        {
foreach (DictionaryEntry docDic in department.Doctor)
        {
foreach (Doctor doc in docDic.Value)//this is where I gets an error
{

if (doc.ID.Equals(docID))//find the doctor specified
{
}
}
}
}
```

But I can not compile the program. It gives an **Error**:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because
'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

Comment: You should be using generics for this. See the [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through a dictionary entry's `Value` field treating it as if it was a collection of `Doctor`s.  The iteration for `docDic` should already do what you are looking for, just need to cast the appropriate field (probably `Value`) of the `docDic` `DictionaryEntry`.

```
Doctor doc = (Doctor) docDic.Value;
```

Better yet, you could use generics and denote the types of the dictionary key/value at declaration of the map:

```
private Hashtable<string, Doctor> doctors = new Hashtable<string, Doctor>();
```

(similar change for the `Doctor` field)

Then you don't need the casting above at all.

*Note*: I assumed you are mapping from a doctor's id (key) to the `Doctor` objects (value), and that the id is a string

Comment: Yes you r8. I was iterating though dictionary entry that's what the probelm. I think your second sugessted method would more appropriate for me. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your class with a **Public** access modifier

```
 public  class Department
{
private string departmentId;
private string departmentName;
private Hashtable doctors = new Hashtable();//Store doctors for 
                                            //each department
 public Hashtable Doctor  
{
 get { return doctors; }
  }
 }
```

Comment: the problem was, as "Attila" said, the dictionary entry. Any ways thanx for your help